# deploy django-app to heroku - Application error

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Django app to Heroku. I am following all the steps mentioned on Heroku dev center https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration. The app deploys successfully but when I run `heroku open` or manually visit the link it shows

> Application error
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
> served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
> You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs
> --tail

My Logs:

```
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515968+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515969+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515970+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515970+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515970+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515970+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515971+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515971+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515972+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515972+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515973+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515973+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515973+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515974+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515974+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515974+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-07-13T18:26:37.515975+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'        
2021-07-13T18:26:37.516146+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:37 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-07-13T18:26:37.520489+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:37 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527381+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:37 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527382+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527383+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527383+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527384+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527384+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527385+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527387+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527388+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527388+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527389+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527389+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527389+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527390+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527390+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527391+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527391+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527392+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527392+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527392+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527393+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527393+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527394+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527394+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527394+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527395+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'        
2021-07-13T18:26:37.527519+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:37 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-07-13T18:26:37.575136+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:37 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 7 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-07-13T18:26:37.677918+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:37 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-07-13T18:26:37.678111+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:37 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-07-13T18:26:37.781026+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-07-13T18:26:37.959596+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-13T18:26:37.964944+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-07-13T18:26:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-07-13T18:26:55.063317+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn myproject.wsgi`
2021-07-13T18:26:59.003109+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-07-13T18:26:59.003975+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:50049 (4)
2021-07-13T18:26:59.004155+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-07-13T18:26:59.013689+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:59 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020640+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:59 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020665+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020672+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020677+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020678+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020678+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020679+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020679+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020684+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020685+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020685+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020686+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020686+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020686+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020687+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020687+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020687+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020688+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020688+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020689+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020689+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020690+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020690+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020691+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020691+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020692+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'        
2021-07-13T18:26:59.020997+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:59 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-07-13T18:26:59.089336+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-07-13T18:26:59.089511+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-13 18:26:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-07-13T18:26:59.214561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-07-13T18:26:59.325816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-13T18:27:01.234730+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=heyady.herokuapp.com request_id=a7547546-fb0f-4a00-83ea-619e7128aef1 fwd="169.149.36.45" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-07-13T18:27:01.959325+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=heyady.herokuapp.com request_id=8d35e215-091f-432f-abf1-1a3dae52be5b fwd="169.149.36.45" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-07-13T18:28:08.924235+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user adyyousf197@gmail.com
2021-07-13T18:28:21.919810+00:00 heroku[run.5856]: State changed from starting to up
7a-acd0aab16891 fwd="169.149.22.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-07-13T18:28:36.667998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
host=heyady.herokuapp.com request_id=2896e5e2-150f-4d77-a0c2-ecf77ce4e5a2 fwd="169.149.22.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Hi Ady! Log is showing that the module "my_project" was not found. 

Some place on your code importing or referencing "my_project" and it not be installed.

Check if "my_project" is a name of your app and if is listed on 'INSTALLED_APPS' on settings.py

Comment: Hey Marcello! Thanks for replying. I did notice that error but i couldn't find where this module is. I was working on a different project before where I created a virtualenv by name myproject. I copied some template code from there but i can't find where I'm referencing the same in this app. I checked my installed_apps and it's not there.

Comment: A tip is (in your IDE, I use Visual Studio) you search for "myproject " (without quotes)   in root dir of your project, will show all files that has "my_project" in code. Maybe is easier to find. Because some where is referencing to "myproject".

Comment: @MarcelloBastos Yes, I did it the same way, found out my Proctile was referencing it. Appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of research  and reading the Django docs, Heroku docs, StackOverflow articles I found that I was doing it wrong all the time and because I read similar articles where people have the same problem. Maybe this is going to help you:

1. The Procfile has no extensions.
2. You should be deploying through a virtual environment
3. the Procfile script is important  and you need to add `web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi` where `myproject` is to be replaced by the name of your project.
4. Make sure the Procfile is within your root directory and not inside a project subfolder.

Comment: So the error was the reference to "myproject" in somewhere in code. Happy to help you Ady!